# python add string to the start of each element in array

Tags: python

In the following i have an array where for each element a string should be added at the start and not append ,how can i do this

```
 a=["Hi","Sam","How"]
 I want to add "Hello" at the start of each element so that the output will be

 Output:

 a=["HelloHi","HelloSam","HelloHow"]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for a list of strings:

```
a = ['Hello'+b for b in a]
```

and this works for other objects too (uses their strings representation):

```
a = ['Hello{}'.format(b) for b in a]
```

Example:

```
a = ["Hi", "Sam", "How", 1, {'x': 123}, None]
a = ['Hello{}'.format(b) for b in a]
# ['HelloHi', 'HelloSam', 'HelloHow', 'Hello1', "Hello{'x': 123}", 'HelloNone']
```

Comment: To allow non-string objects using the `+` operator you can simply add a call to `str`. `str.format` is about 15% slower than using the string concatenation(and more than 50% slower than string concatenation without calling `str`. Even though probably every solution proposed is efficient enough in almost all situations).

Answer (score 1):

```
a=["Hi","Sam","How"]
a = ["hello" + x for x in a]
print a
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `map`:

```
map('Hello{0}'.format,a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
>>> def say_hello(foo):
...   return 'Hello{}'.format(foo)
... 
>>> map(say_hello,['hi','there'])
['Hellohi', 'Hellothere']
```